# How do I access LocalStorage variables at the ready function in Polymer using iron-localstorage?

Tags: polymer, local-storage

I want to access some data from the LocalStorage at the ready function, however, it seems they have not been initialized so far. does anyone have a workout about this.

I have this piece of code:

```
<iron-localstorage
   name="language"
   value="{{ language }}"
   useRaw="true"
   on-iron-localstorage-load-empty="initializeDefaultLanguage">
</iron-localstorage>

Polymer({
        is: 'banner-card',

        language : {
            type: String,
        },

        ready : function(){
               console.log(this.language); //undefined
        }, 
        initializeDefaultLanguage:function(e){
            this.set("language","Spanish");
        }

});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: could you show your code?

Comment: I just updated !

Comment: I think localstorage is ready after the `ready` polymer event. This is why language is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I should have not used `ready` to get the current information of my localstorage, instead I should use this event

```
iron-localstorage-load
```